# How to restrict user to select not more than 10 asp.net checkboxes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to restrict user to select not more than 10 asp.net checkboxes on button click event , if user select more than 10 checkboxes then alert box will pop up that you can not select more than 10 checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and implement its [`ServerValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx) event (and, optionally, do the same thing on the client via its [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)).

Maybe something like this (if you're using jQuery):

### ASPX

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Checkboxes" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CheckboxValidator" runat="server" Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="CheckboxValidator_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="CheckboxValidator_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Too many selections" />
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckboxValidator_ClientValidate(sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = jQuery('#<%=Checkboxes.ClientID%> input:checked').length < <%= MaximumSelections %>;
    }
</script>
```

### Codebehind

```
protected const int MaximumSelections = 10;

protected void CheckboxValidator_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = Checkboxes.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Count() < MaximumSelections;
}
```

Comment: How to do it ..m the basic learner can u give a simple example

Answer (score 2):

If there are not many check boxes on the page, then create a onlcick javascript function for the checkbox and loop through all the check box to see if more than 10 is checked.

If there are a lot of checkbox on your page, then increment a variable when the checkbox is clicked and decrement it when its unchecked. You will have the count always which you can check to display the alert.

Comment: can u plz provide me the example for thsi ?